# Having an item appear conditionally in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I have a Nav component:

```
class SomeClass extends React.Component{
    
    showItem = () =>{
        console.log("itemShown");
        return(
            <Item/>
        );
    }
    
    render(){
    
        return(
            <div onClick={() => this.showItem()} >
                ABC
            </div>
        );
}

export default Nav;
```

I am calling it in App.js:

```
function App() {
  return (
      <div className="app">
          <SomeClass />
      </div>
    );
    
}

export default App;
```

How to have the **Item** component in the **showItem** method in **SomeClass**, to be shown in the **App** functional component.

In **App.js** I tried:

```
<div className="app">
    <SomeClass showItem={showItem} />
</div>
```

However, it did not work.

What is the best approach to this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These days people don't tend to use react classes, they use functional components. Here's how you do it with functional components.

State Hook:

`toggleShowItem` swaps the `showItem` state between `true` and `false` when ever the `SomeClass` (which isn't a class anymore but that's what you have named yours) component's `onClick` is fired.

Conditional Rendering:

The `ShowItem` is rendered whenever the state hook's value is `true`.

```
export default function App() {
    const [showItem, setShowItem] = useState(false);

    const toggleShowItem = () => {
        setShowItem(!showItem);
    }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <SomeClass toggleShowItem={toggleShowItem}>
                {showItem && <ShowItem />}
            </SomeClass>
        </div>
    );
}

export default function SomeClass({toggleShowItem}) {
    return <div onClick={toggleShowItem}>ABC</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can manage a state inside your `SomeClass` component as follows. Then you can toggle it whenever you need to show or un-show the `Item` component.

```
class SomeClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isShowItem: false,
    };
    this.showItem = this.showItem.bind(this);
  }

  showItem = () => {
    this.setState(!this.state.isShowItem);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div onClick={this.showItem}>ABC</div>
        {this.state.isShowItem && <Item />}
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default SomeClass;
```

Answer (score 1):

The better way to show the `Item` component is to use [React State](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) and [React Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html). Please read this docs since it will help you greatly on react development.

Option 1:

there will be a state in the `App` component for `showItem`. Then you pass the `showItem` as props in the `SomeClass` component.

Option 2:

the state for `showItem` is in the `SomeClass` Component, then upon clicking the toggle, the state will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use two ways.
as react update only when there is some change in state. you are not manipulating any state
other way is making from display: none to display: block